# Get TIFF tag value (including non-ASCII characters) from TIFF images in Java 11

Tags: utf-8, tiff, java-11, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to read different tag values (like tags 259 (Compression), 33432 (Copyright), 306 (DateTime), 315 (Artist) etc.) from a TIFF image in Java. Can anyone suggest what is best way to get those values in Java 11 ?

i tried to get those values using tiffinfo commands (like "`tiffinfo -c myfile.tif`"). But i did not find any specific command in tiffinfo (libtiff) or any Java library which will give me the specific tag values (e.g. DateTime) of a TIFF image.

Update:

As haraldK suggested, i tried with ImageIO like following

```
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(tiffFile)) {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next(); // TODO: Handle reader not found

    reader.setInput(input);
    IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0); 

    TIFFDirectory ifd = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata​(metadata);
    TIFFField dateTime = ifd.get​TIFFField(306); 
    String dateString = dateTime.getAsString(0);  
}
```

But it does not give exact value of the tag. In case of non-ASCII value (ö, ü, ä etc), question marks replace the real values.

Can anyone tell me how to get the exact value (including non-ASCII) of the tag from TIFFField ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard ImageIO, read the TIFF image metadata and get the requested values from it, like this by using some extra support classes in the JDK, starting from Java 9:

```java
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(tiffFile)) {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next(); // TODO: Handle reader not found

    reader.setInput(input);
    IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0); // 0 is the index of first image

    TIFFDirectory ifd = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata​(metadata);
    TIFFField dateTime = ifd.get​TIFFField(306); // Yes, that's 3 F's...
    String dateString = dateTime.getAsString(0); // TIFF dates are strings...
}
```

`tiffFile` must be a valid (existing, readable) `java.io.File`, `java.io.RandomAccessFile` or `java.io.InputStream` (or other supported input, this is plugin-based, really). If not, `input` will be `null`, and the code will fail.

---

You can use similar, but a lot more verbose version, that will work in older versions of Java, as long as you have a TIFF plugin:

```java
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(tiffFile)) {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next(); // TODO: Handle reader not found

    reader.setInput(input);
    IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0); // 0 is the index of first image
    // Get "native" TIFF metadata for first IFD
    IIOMetadataNode root = metadata.getAsTree("com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_image_1.0");
    Node ifd = root.getFirstChild();
    NodeList fields = ifd.getElementsByTagName("TIFFField"); // Yes, that's 3 F's...
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.getLength(); i++) {
        Element field = (Element) fields.item(i);

        if ("306".equals(field.getAttribute("number"))) {
            // This is your DateTime (306) tag, 
            // now do something with it 
            // ...
        }
     }
}
```

Hardly elegant code, though... The Java 9+ approach is much cleaner and easier to reason about.

Comment: thank you for your answer. for TIFFField,  javax.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFField; should be imported. right ? But it still shows error : Cannot resolve symbol 'TIFField'. do you have any idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, it was a typo. It's `TIFFField` (3 Fs...). Fixed.

Comment: value of tiffFile is /home/IdeaProjects/myfile/mytiff.tif. why is it getting null value ?

Comment: `tiffFile` needs to be a valid (and existing and readable) `java.io.File` or `InputStream`. But I'm assuming you know where your files are located, it has nothing to do with the above code. 

Comment: location of the file is correct. i already worked with the image. when i debug, execution of the code stops at ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next();

Comment: @Raz Sorry, I cannot help you debug the file system on your computer. I don't even know what your code looks like. The above code works for me. It will work for you too, but you need to make sure the path is correct. If you have trouble sorting out how to do that in Java, please go ahead and ask a new question, and include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: i am using same code. i added this line before your code File tiff = new File(/home/IdeaProjects/myfile/mytiff.tif); Now null error has gone. but when i debug, the execution stops at IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

Comment: @Raz *“execution stops”*? Does it hang? Throw an exception? Die suddenly? Stack trace? Error code? Please be more specific.

Comment: error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set!

Comment: Ah, ok. Makes sense. I forgot I line when copy/pasting, sorry. We also need `reader.setInput(input)`, see the updated code in the answer. But as you see, the exception message literally tells you what to do...

Comment: thank you. now TIFFField dateTime = ifd.get​TIFFField(306); should return a DateTime or any string value. right ? But it returns javax.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFField@4923ab24. how can i get the real tag value here ?

Comment: It's a [TIFFField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFField.html)... See the API doc for options. The `DateTime` field is really just an ASCII field, so you can use `dateTime.getAsString(0)`, to get the value as in the TIFF. You need to further parse it to get a `Date` or `DateTime` object, but I leave that to you now...

Comment: thank you. it shows another problem. if the tag value of the image has umlaut (ä), it replaces the umlaut with question mark. i need the value including umlaut. how to get the real value including umlaut ? :D

Comment: Seriously. I think I have answered your question. And more. You should probably accept it. And if that answer lead to a new question, then feel free to ask it. But as a question, rather than in an endless chain of comments.

Comment: this is last question :D

Comment: The short answer is: TIFF ASCII fields cannot contain umlauts, as it is strictly 7 bit ASCII (and the high bit must be 0).

Comment: then how to get the real values including umlaut ? please give a solution